# How to solve a discrete dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems, matrix-equations

I am working through an example to solve the following system but I believe there might be typing errors in the book I will type it exactly as in the book

$x(n+1)= \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\0 & 2 &\end{bmatrix}x(n)+\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1 &\end{bmatrix}$

Then the fixed point is given by:
$x_*= \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\0 & 2 &\end{bmatrix}x_*+\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-1 &\end{bmatrix}$

Therefore
$\begin{bmatrix} 1& 1\\0 & 1 &\end{bmatrix}x(n)+\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-1 
&\end{bmatrix}=0$

and hence $x_*=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1 &\end{bmatrix}$

$X(n)=x(n)-x_*$

then
$X(n+1)= \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\0 & 2 &\end{bmatrix}X(n)$

the eigenvalue equation is $(\lambda-2)^2=0$ with $\lambda_1=2$

let $K_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0 &\end{bmatrix}$

I am not going to type the rest but I am sure there are errors.
can anyone refer me to a proper worked example of a similar system.

Comment: Looks fine to me... What exactly do you think is wrong?

Comment: from the first line to the 2nd the 2 changed sign?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right! So supposedly it should have been $-2$ from the beginning, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Correction*:

$x(n+1)= \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\0 & 2 &\end{bmatrix}x(n)+\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1 &\end{bmatrix}\ \ \ \ $ (Eq. 1)

Then the fixed point is given by ($x(n+1)=x(n)=x_*$):

$x_*= \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\0 & 2 &\end{bmatrix}x_*+\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1 &\end{bmatrix}$

Therefore
$\begin{bmatrix} 1& 1\\0 & 1 &\end{bmatrix}x_*=\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1 
&\end{bmatrix}$

and hence $x_*=\begin{bmatrix}-3\\1 &\end{bmatrix}$

Redefine zero: $X(n)=x(n)-x_*$ (substitute in Eq. 1)

then
$X(n+1)= \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\0 & 2 &\end{bmatrix}X(n)$

The eigenvalue equation is $(\lambda-2)^2=0$ with $\lambda_{1,2}=2$

let $K_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0 &\end{bmatrix}$

*I do not know what the rest of the exercise is.*

Comment: That is the same result I got thank you, would you mind to complete the answer to the general solution as every thing below this is based in wrong information